# Method for scanning a website database for signs of hacking

Tags: mysql, security, drupal, sql-injection

I am trying to determine if there are any good methods for scanning a website database to determine if the site has been compromised.  I am reviewing a Drupal website which may have been exposed to an SQL injection vulnerability.

I understand that hackers will often hide code in the database using hexadecimal literals to avoid filters.

I am wondering if there was any method or tool one could use to scan a database for suspicious content?

Comment: diff it against the most recent backup

Answer (score -1):

If your database is changing constantly.. then it is very difficult to know if your database is exploited (involves cyber forensics).

Also, many of the SQL injection attacks involve gathering information than modifying.

There are tools for checking the vulnerabilities of a site. You can use them to patch the vulnerabilities instead.

You can use the following tools for this purpose:

- [SQLNinja](http://sqlninja.sourceforge.net/)
- [SQLMap](http://sqlmap.org/)

Source: [Automated SQL injection Detection](https://www.arneswinnen.net/2013/09/automated-sql-injection-detection/)

Comment: Thanks for the useful links.  In this case the issue is whether the site has been compromised, rather than is it vulnerable.  I known that the site was vulnerable to the Drupal SA-CORE-2014-005 SQL injection exploit.  I was wondering if it might be possible to dump the database and then scan it with something to see if it has been compromised.